# How can I set the notification sound with a file that is inside the app private folder?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an mp3 file inside the app folder. I can access it via `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`, but I am having no success in using as the sound to be played for a notification.

My goal is to allow the user to download custom tones and I don't want to override the default app sounds, so the ringtones are being stored in the aforementioned files directory.

How can I get the correct path for the file to be used as a notification sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the file URI to your notification by using the [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider). e.g.:

```
val file = File(fileAbsolutePath)
FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, file)
```

Also, you'll have to declare the provider on your `AndroidManifest.xml`, like the example below:

```
<provider
   android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="your authority here"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">

    <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>

</provider>
```

As for the `file_paths`, you'll have to declare which files will be available. As stated on the docs:

> **A FileProvider can only generate a content URI for files in
>   directories that you specify beforehand.** To specify a directory,
>   specify the its storage area and path in XML, using child elements of
>   the  element.

For example:

```
<files-path name="my_audios" path="audios/" />
```

The tag name will define the base folder from where you're reading the files.

- `<files-path ... />` will map to `files/` which is the same path you get from `Context.getFilesDir()`.
- `<cache-path ... />` will lead to the cache subdirectory of your app, which is the same path as `getCacheDir()`.
- `<external-path ... />` points to the root of your external storage media. Same as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.
- `<external-files-path ... />` leads to the root of your app's external storage area. Same path as: `Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)`.

There are other possible base paths. For the full list, check the docs on how to [define the provider available files](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#ProviderDefinition).

**Obs.:** As you stated on your comment, the audio files you want to play shouldn't have special characters, underscores or any other restricted character. Name the file as you would name the `/res` resource files.

Comment: Perfect. I was having trouble with the notification not being able to play the sound, even tho the `FileProvider` was returning the correct path. Turns out the sound file name must not contain underscores and other restricted characters. Once I fixed that the notification played the sound perfectly (I changed the name to only lower case letters).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The file name must not contain any of those characters, just like anything you place inside the res folder ;)

Comment: Just an update; Android 7.1 and above have a bug since 2016 that prevents any custom sound from being read by the notification center, meaning that no custom sound can be used in recent Android versions: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36524161